# Как при прокрутке страницы до конца менять фон одного из элементов?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при прокрутке страницы до конца менять background у элемента(4)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подключаешь jQuery. Вот тебе скрипт.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
block = false;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() && !block) {
    block = true;
    /* функция меняющяя цвет*/
    loadContent();
}
}); 
});
```