# Как показывать подвал, только если страница прокручена до конца?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Хотелось бы на чистом CSS, на jQuery есть решение.

Comment: Можете добавить пример или jQuery-решение? Чем то, что вам нужно, отличается от обычного подвала в конце страницы?

Comment: Да легко. А в чём проблема-то?

Comment: @Gleb Kemarsky [вот почти полное jQuery-решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/409768/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) В моём случае должен будет появляться блок с подвалом. Нужный вариант отличается тем, что подвал как бы выезжает из-под страницы при полном пролистывании.

Comment: @Qwerity Проблема как раз в том, что я не знаю как это сделать на CSS и мне интересно узнать, как это делается. Буду благодарен, если вы покажете как.

Comment: В CSS не перехватить текущий скролл окна. Ровно как и виден ли элемент во вьюпорте в данный момент. Правильно на JS сделать - зачем костыли лепить.

Comment: Ловите момент, когда страница прокручена до конца и даёте нужный CSS-класс с анимацией подвалу. Как определить что страница прокручена до конца в инете полно материала. Можно с JSR черпануть знаний: https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window.

Answer (score 2):

> Как показывать подвал, только если страница прокручена до конца?

```css
body {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

main, footer {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

footer {
  background: #333;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 1s 1s ease-in-out both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes show {
  from {  opacity: 0;}
  to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes show {
  from {  opacity: 0;}
  to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <main>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, eum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A sint aliquam molestiae facilis nobis nostrum eveniet tempora, harum tenetur magni recusandae aut minus nemo odio, quas, soluta neque doloribus aliquid. Illum quam, nisi? Excepturi ut nobis necessitatibus illum suscipit esse officia nostrum animi asperiores autem nam iusto debitis unde delectus exercitationem soluta nisi provident quos, quas dolorum. Praesentium quibusdam maiores aliquid eius, voluptatem iusto deleniti illo. Iure officia fuga ratione nisi, neque, doloremque explicabo quibusdam laudantium nihil fugit! Commodi perspiciatis ratione porro aut, nobis pariatur consectetur eius id. Laborum impedit illum et cupiditate quas reiciendis laboriosam excepturi itaque culpa necessitatibus.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, eum.</p>
    </main>

    <footer>
      &copy 2016
    </footer>
    
  </div>
```

Если только css то только так).

События скролл + определения положения (верхняя точка\нижняя точка окна) еще не придумали в css увы.

Как вариант можно перед футером делать блок (не видимый) или использовать последний параграф, при наведении на который появлялся бы футер, но это если пользователь наведет мышью на этот блок, а не будет просто скролить.